# How to prevent the infinit loop for wordbreak

Tags: java

```
public boolean wordBreak(String s, Set<String> dict) {

    if(s.length()==0)  return true;

    String first = null;
    boolean isOk= false;

    for(int i=1; i<s.length(); i++){
        first = s.substring(0,i);
        if(dict.contains(first)){
            String remaining = s.substring(i);
            isOk = wordBreak(remaining, dict);
            if(dict.contains(remaining))
                isOk=true;
            if(isOk)
                return isOk;

        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

I cannot pass the infinite loop for the case: 
"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab"

executed input: ["a","aa","aaa","aaaa","aaaaa","aaaaaa","aaaaaaa","aaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaaa"]
Can anyone help me to point the mistake in the logic? Thanks

Comment: What is the expected behavior? Could you describe what the method is supposed to do?

Comment: You can step through you code in a debugger to find the answer yourself. Some of your code doesn't appear to be doing anything useful so it is hard to suggest what it should be doing.

Comment: Do you really need substring(0,0) when i=0 ?

Comment: Can you please tell, What is the input and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have an infinite loop, you have infinite recursion.  This is because when you call this method with a String, the first thing you do is call itself with the same string.

Also you check for contains() a couple of times but you never update dict so its not clear when this will be true.

> executed input: ["a","aa","aaa","aaaa","aaaaa","aaaaaa","aaaaaaa","aaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaaa"] Can anyone help me to point the mistake in the logic?

Some points

- you don't update the `dict` set anywhere.
- you call the same function with the same arguments so it is going to repeat without stopping.
- If this is all you require, a loop or a pair of loops would be simpler, and more likely to work.

I am not sure what it does exactly but what you could do is

```
public void wordBreak(String s, Set<String> dict) {
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        for(int j = i + 1; j < s.length(); j++)
            dict.add(s.substring(i, j));
}
```